# How to know if now time is between two hours?

Tags: java, android, time, format, hour

I have a now time:

```
new Date();
```

And I have some hour constants, for example, **23** and **8** (it's 11pm or 23:00, 8am or 08:00).
How I can know is now time between it's two hour constants?

*It need to run some code of program or not to run if now time is between in two hours, for example, do not run some code if its already evening and while it is not a morning.*

Here the image to better explain:

[image]

**Some situations when silent mode does not fire:**

```
00:00 20.06.13 - 23:00 20.06.13 // after 23.00 can loud!!

23:00 20.06.13 - 15:00 20.06.13 // after 15.00 can loud!!

01:00 20.06.13 - 08:00 20.06.13 // after 08.00 can loud!!

21:00 20.06.13 - 08:00 20.06.13 // after 08.00 can loud!!
```

Comment: Did you try something yet?

Comment: I try but nothing. I confuse with time's functions in java, it's really a lot of methods.

Comment: You want to compare only *time*.  So `Jan 1 00:00:00 GMT 2013` and `Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT 2014` would be between 2 hours, right?

Comment: And lo!  There are answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/17212955/2235132 to prove that!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try this

```
    int from = 2300;
    int to = 800;
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    int t = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 100 + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    boolean isBetween = to > from && t >= from && t <= to || to < from && (t >= from || t <= to);
```

Comment: It seems your code works fine. I think I will use it. Only you could not tell what hour multiplied by a hundred?

Comment: it is only to make comparison simpler, otherwise we should compare hours and minutes separately

Comment: Thanks.. it helped me

Answer (score 15):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //Create Calendar-Object
cal.setTime(new Date());               //Set the Calendar to now
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //Get the hour from the calendar
if(hour <= 23 && hour >= 8)              // Check if hour is between 8 am and 11pm
{
     // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I think it must be replaced with: `if(hour <=23 && hour >=8) { // do what I need }`. It is not be working if first hour is 01:00.

Comment: I think the if i wrote is right. I think the wants the program to run when it´s night.

Comment: Sorry, but I little bit don't understood what you said

Comment: It´s so simple. Just get a Calendar and then get the Hour from the Calendar. Then Check if the Hour is after 23:00 at night and before 8:00 in the morning

Comment: You have to care about 0:00 especially. E.g. if hourfrom == 0 then hourfrom = 24

Answer (score 11):

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. Much of the functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the ThreeTen-Backport project and further adapted to Android in ThreeTenABP project.

Time zone is crucial here. For any given moment, the date and time-of-day both vary around the world by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

Get your current moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Extract the time-of-day. The `Local` part of the name means there is *no* concept of time zone contained within the object.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime();
```

Define the limits of the evening.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of( 23 , 0 );  // 11 PM.
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 );  // 8 AM.
```

Compare.

- We need to figure out if we are straddling over a new day or within the same day. A `LocalTime` has no concept of date, only a single generic day of 24 hours. So we must test if the start is before or after the stop as we need different comparison algorithm for each case. And we should consider if the start *equals* the stop, as that may be a special case depending on your business rules.
- In date-time work, we usually define spans of time as Half-Open, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

Here's one way to do it.

```
Boolean silentRunning = null ;
if( start.equals( stop ) ) {
    silentRunning = Boolean.FALSE ;
} else if( stop.isAfter( start ) ) {  // Example 3 PM to 6 PM.
    silentRunning = ( ! lt.isBefore( start ) ) && lt.isBefore( stop ) ;
} else if ( stop.isBefore( start ) ) {  // Example 11 PM to 8 AM.
    silentRunning = ( lt.equals( start ) || lt.isAfter( start ) ) && lt.isBefore( stop ) ;
} else {
    // Error. Should not reach this point. Paranoid check.
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

UPDATE: The above is a later version of this Answer. Below is the old.

## Joda-Time

The Joda-Time library is vastly superior to the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes for date-time work.

Time zone is crucial for determine the time of day. Obviously "now" is later in the day in Paris than Montréal.

Definig a range of time is usually best done as half-open, `[)`, where the beginning is inclusive but the ending is exclusive.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( zone );
Integer hour = now.getHourOfDay();
Boolean isNight = ( ( hour >= 23  ) && ( hour < 8 ) );
```

Answer (score 7):

I think that this is more cleaner solution and it`s works. I have tested it with different time parameters.

```
        /**
         * @param fromHour Start Time
         * @param toHour Stop Time
         * @param now Current Time
         * @return true if Current Time is between fromHour and toHour
         */
        boolean isTimeBetweenTwoHours(int fromHour, int toHour, Calendar now) {
            //Start Time
            Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
            from.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, fromHour);
            from.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            //Stop Time
            Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();
            to.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, toHour);
            to.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

            if(to.before(from)) {
                if (now.after(to)) to.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                else from.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            }
            return now.after(from) && now.before(to);
        }
```

Comment: thank you! it works much better than any other solutions provided here!

Answer (score 2):

You can see a tutorial  [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/date_before.htm) with `Date.before` and you can do with `Date.after`

Also you can get his milliseconds and compare it.

Answer (score 1):

here is a function that checks is now(current time) is either between 
1 to 4 OR
4 to 8 OR
8 to 12 OR
12 to 16 OR
16 to 20 OR
20 to 1 And returns next accuring time.

```
private Calendar GetTimeDiff() throws ParseException {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar one = Calendar.getInstance();
    one.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
    one.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    one.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar four = Calendar.getInstance();
    four.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
    four.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    four.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar eight = Calendar.getInstance();
    eight.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    eight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    eight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar twelve = Calendar.getInstance();
    twelve.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    twelve.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    twelve.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar sixteen = Calendar.getInstance();
    sixteen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    sixteen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    sixteen.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar twenty = Calendar.getInstance();
    twenty.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    twenty.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    twenty.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if(now.getTime().after(one.getTime()) && now.getTime().before(four.getTime())) {
        return four;
    }

    if(now.getTime().after(four.getTime()) && now.getTime().before(eight.getTime())) {
        return eight;
    } 

    if(now.getTime().after(eight.getTime()) && now.getTime().before(twelve.getTime())) {
        return twelve;
    } 

    if(now.getTime().after(twelve.getTime()) && now.getTime().before(sixteen.getTime())) {
        return sixteen;
    } 

    if(now.getTime().after(sixteen.getTime()) && now.getTime().before(twenty.getTime())) {
        return twenty;
    } 

    if(now.getTime().after(twenty.getTime()) && now.getTime().before(one.getTime())) {
        return one;
    }

    return now;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Solution**

I wasn't able to find a solution for this in PHP, but @sytolk answer helped. heres the PHP version.

```
// $current = Date('H:i:s');
$current = "01:00:00";
$start = "23:00:00";
$end = "02:00:00";

$current = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $current);
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $start);
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $end);

if ($end < $start) {
    if ($current > $end) {
        $end->modify('+1 day');
    } else {
        $start->modify('-1 day');
    }
}

$inTime = $current > $start && $current < $end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also convert your input string to an integer and compare it against your constants. This way you don't even need to work with the Calendar and Date objects.

```
public class testDateRange {

    static final int START_HOUR = 8;
    static final int END_HOUR = 23;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String now_time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
        System.err.println(isInRange(Integer.parseInt(now_time.replace(":","")),START_HOUR*100,END_HOUR*100));

    }

    private static boolean isInRange(int now_time, int start_time, int end_time) {

       if ((now_time>start_time)&&
               (now_time<end_time)       )
       {
        return true;
       }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could we use this code if START_HOUR = 23  and END_HOUR = 23?